# CMS fails at finishing setup with PHP-FPM and Apache, but why?

Tags: php, apache, cms

I have installed Apache and PHP-FPM by following [this tutorial](https://alexcabal.com/installing-apache-mod_fastcgi-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-server-maverick/).

Unfortunately when I try to set up Drupal or PHP-Fusion it simply fails at the end of the setup. I mean it accepts everything and at the last step it does not load anything but a blank page. I suppose I have not installed a required PHP package, but I do not know which one it is.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally check out [Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/158043) for the white screen error. It seems to me it is trying to do something after you install but can not serve content (based on my failed cms install (wordpress first time install) but I would also make sure file permissions for your cms is setup correctly. Most cms' also (for one feature or another) seem to need mod_rewrite enabled. Once I had my permissions setup correctly, and made sure mod_rewrite was active and working it cleared my error right up. Just a shot "in the dark" but worked for me.